# maintaining focus in user controls Windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

I am having a windows application using c#. I have created a form `frmMain` which loads when user logs in. There are 4 options for the user like *Customer Creation*, *Supplier Creation*, *Employee Creation*, *User Creation*

[image: Situation example]

This works fine.

**The issue arises with focus**. When the user loads `Customer` user control and filling in some data and let's suppose user is somewhere on 4th control (`Textbox`/`Combobox` or any other Windows Forms input control) and suddenly he clicks on `CreateUser`, then `CreateUser` control loads, but the focus remains on the 4th control in `Customer` user control.

What I want is to set focus on the current user control where user left it from else if it is newly loaded set focus on default control.

Please check the code which I am using,

```
// this method gets called if the form was opened earlier
  private void ShowOpenForm(ControlItem _item)
        {
            try
            {
                //Get item from menu
                ControlItem _menuI = null;
                foreach (ToolStripmenuI menuI in tsmenuWindow.DropDownItems)
                {
                    _menuI = (ControlItem)menuI.Tag;
                    if (_menuI.Control.Name.ToLower() == _item.Control.Name.ToLower())
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    _menuI = null;
                }
                if (_menuI != null)
                {
                    WmenuI_ClearAllSelection();
                    for (int index = 0; index < PnlUserCtrl.Controls.Count; index++)
                    {
                        Control ctl = PnlUserCtrl.Controls[index];
                        if (ctl.Name.ToLower() == _menuI.Control.Name.ToLower())
                        {
                            ctl.Visible = true;
                            ctl.BringToFront();


                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    WmenuI_SetCurrentItemChecked(_menuI);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }









//User can navigate to opened items from menu as well

  private void WindowMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ControlItem _item = (ControlItem)((ToolStripMenuItem)sender).Tag;
                WmenuI_ClearAllSelection();
                for (int index = 0; index <  PnlUserCtrl.Controls.Count; index++)
                {
                    Control ctl =  PnlUserCtrl.Controls[index];
                    if (ctl.Name.ToLower() == _item.Control.Name.ToLower())
                    {
                        ctl.Visible = true;
                        ctl.BringToFront();
                        if (ctl is BaseControl)
                        {
                            ((BaseControl)ctl).SetFocus();  // This sets the focus to default textbox
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                }
                WmenuI_SetCurrentItemChecked(_item);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

But this set focus on the default textbox. Not on the control from where user moves to other user control.

Comment: Just set the focus on the user control.  Since UserControl never wants the focus, it automagically moves the focus to the control with the lowest TabIndex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good practice to supply some code in your questions for the sake of getting better answers.
You can manually manipulate focus as you want using `SetFocus()` method. For your question I believe you can have a object of type `Control` then you can set it to default control you want to focus on. Then you handle all `GotFocus` methods of your controls and set the value of that object.
Whenever you want focus restored to last item you can call `[your object].SetFocus()`.
This is just an idea. See if it helps.

Comment: This is terrible advice. Never change the focus within a GotFocus event handler! This is called out explicitly in the MSDN documentation.

Comment: @CodyGray Who said you should do that??? I said you set an object in got focus to hold the last item that had the focus. Then SetFocus will be called in another event caused by create user.